# angularjs custom filter dynamic server call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I would like to call a server-side service when my filter is empty.
this is my HTML:

```
<html lang="en">  
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf 8">
    <title>test angular</title>     
</head>  
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
<h1 ng-app="app" ng-controller="HelloWorldCtrl">{{message}}</h1>
<p><input type="text"  id="myfilter" ng-model="seachText"></p>
<div ng-app="app" id="search" ng-controller="serviceCall">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in lau | myfilter:seachText">
    {{ x.des }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

and this is my code:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("serviceCall", function($scope, $http) {
    var v=document.getElementById('search').value;
    if (!v){v="Vigo";}
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1/KLAU.pl?search="+v+"&lim=10").then(function(response) {
    $scope.lau = response.data;
  });
});
app.filter('myfilter', [function($scope){
  return function(input, param) {
      if(!angular.isDefined(param)) param = '';             
      var ret = [];
      angular.forEach(input, function(v){
                var regx=new RegExp(param, 'gi');
                if(regx.test(v.des)){
                     ret.push(v);
                     console.log("match!!");
                }
      });
      if (!ret.length ){
            $scope.serviceCall();
      }
      return ret;
  };
}]);
```

I'm getting:
typeError: "$scope is undefined".

thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope` does not work in filter. Better inject a service, or pass the service function as another parameter to the filter:

```js
  return function(input, param, serviceCall) {   
      //...
      serviceCall()   // replaces $scope.serviceCall();
      //...
   }
```

Make sure you define `serviceCall` in the controller that calls the filter:

```js
app.controller("serviceCall", function($scope, $http) {
    var v=document.getElementById('search').value;
    if (!v){v="Vigo";}
    $scope.serviceCall = function() {
        $http.get("http://127.0.0.1/KLAU.pl?search="+v+"&lim=10").then(function(response) {
            $scope.lau = response.data;
         });
    };
    $scope.serviceCall();
  });
});
```

In HTML:

```html
       <li ng-repeat="x in lau | myfilter:seachText:serviceCall">
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. I tried to implement as suggested,but it is not working (TypeError: "serviceCall is not a function")

Comment: the serviceCall passed as a param is "undefined"

Comment: need to define it in scope. added to answer